# verifying replication_factor in where clause in cassandra query

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to find out whether replication factor of a keyspace is changed or not. I tried following queries and getting syntax error. Can some help me with syntax here?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as rows 
FROM system.schema_keyspaces  
WHERE keyspace_name = 'cluster_test' and strategy_options = {replication_factor:2}

SELECT COUNT(*) as rows 
FROM system.schema_keyspaces  
WHERE keyspace_name = 'cluster_test' and strategy_options['replication_factor'] = '2'
```

Answer (score 1):

`system.schema_keyspaces` is from cassandra 2.x.

Cassandra 3.x has `system_schema.keyspaces`.

Irrespective of version you cannot create secondary index on system keyspaces.

Since there will be only one record for each keyspace in the table (keyspace_name is PRIMARY KEY), you can fetch the record on application side and do comparison.

```
SELECT strategy_options FROM system.schema_keyspaces  
WHERE keyspace_name = 'cluster_test'
```

Answer (score 0):

`strategy_options` is not a clustering column in `system.schema_keyspaces`. You cannot execute the where clause on the non-clustered key column.

Since `system.schema_keyspaces` is system keyspace you cannot create index also.

If you are using the Cassandra 3.0, you can create materialized-view on to `system.schema_keyspaces` and query it to support your filter.
Here is how you can create materialized-view

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW myschema_keyspaces As select * from system.schema_keyspaces primary key (keyspace_name, strategy_options)
```

now you can able to perform your filter criteria on materialized-view `myschema_keyspaces`